# AWS Custom Cookbooks Copy File to instance

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

We are utilizing OpsWorks for our AWS instances. I have several cookbooks out on a git repo utilizing berkshelf for them. From my understanding, the custom chef recipes get copied to each server instance when the instance is fired up (or you update the custom recipes).

I am looking for a chef recipe that will copy a file from the git repo into a directory onto the server instance.

An example would be:
My db.php file is NOT in the git repo for my OpsWorks app. I have it sitting in another git repo where my custom chef cookbooks/recipes are. I want to be able to call a chef recipe that will take that db.php file and copy it into /srv/www/app/current/config/db.php onto the local instance.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put it under `files/` in the cookbook and use a `cookbook_file` resource in your recipe code. You could also use a `template` resource if you wanted to dynamically generate some pieces of it.

Comment: This worked well. However, the cookbook_file docs from Chef state that files can be in the files/ directory. AWS OpsWorks Chef will not utilize any file in the root of files/. It needs to be in files/default/ or files/ubuntu<version>/.

Comment: Support for dropping the `default/` bit was added in Chef 12.0, and OpsWorks on Linux is still running 11.x it seems. Laaaaaame but so it goes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a remote_file resource.

But I don't think that getting one file directly from repo is a good idea.
It is better to clone that repo on machine and checkout specific revision. Other option is to put given file on S3 and update it periodically.